# How to use several mutexes in @GuardedBy annotation?

Tags: java, concurrency, annotations

I have a method which should thread-safely do some processing over multiple fields of the class. This method is called in multiple loops, thus I don't lock any mutexes inside it, but require a caller to lock them, using a `@GuardedBy` annotation, something like this:

```
@GuardedBy("this")
void foo(int x) {
    mField1 = x + mField2;
    mField2 = x;
}
```

But to make my class faster I introduce a fine-grained locking. `mField1` and `mField2` sometimes are updated simultaneously, but sometimes are not, thus I introduce separate locks for them. How do I represent this logic in the annotation?

I tried coding something like

```
@GuardedBy("mField1Lock")
@GuardedBy("mField2Lock")
void foo(int x) {
    mField1 = x + mField2;
    mField2 = x;
}
```

But it does not compile: `error: GuardedBy is not a repeatable annotation type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`@GuardedBy`](http://jcip.net/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/GuardedBy.html) annotation defined by [JCIP (Java Concurrency In Practice)](http://jcip.net/) does not permit multiple mutexes.
Another problem is that JCIP provides no tool to check the annotations, but only uses them as documentation.

The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) solves both of these problems.  Its [`@GuardedBy`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/lock/qual/GuardedBy.html) annotation permits multiple mutexes, and its [Lock Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#lock-checker) verifies the annotations, warning you about anywhere that your code might suffer a race condition due to failure to acquire a lock.